# Symfony 1.4 Installation

Tags: symfony-1.4

How to install symfony 1.4 on Xampp and how to do the web server configurations?  http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/getting-started/1_4/en/05-Web-Server-Configuration as shown in this web page i have done upto web server configurations successfully.
But Configuration testing through this link http://www.myproject.com.localhost/index.php/  is unsuccess.
How to install it properly?

Comment: You should give some more details about the problem you are having. What exact error do you get? Try to follow the guidelines from the tutorial again carefully. Maybe you overlooked a tiny detail.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link, maybe you can help:

http://symfonyandme.com/2013/07/25/instalar-symfony-1-4-en-windows-xp/

The explanation is in Spanish but obviously the code is same for all languages